# Only command after pipe executes, how does the pipe work in these scenarios?

Tags: bash, pipe

What happens in the following two examples? Why is only the second command in each pipeline executed?  How does the pipe work here?

example 1

```
$ cat /var/log/messages | date
Mon Apr  8 17:10:02 IST 2019
```

example 2

```
$ cat /var/log/messages | w
17:10:34 up 8 days,  1:24,  6 users,  load average: 0.63, 0.49, 0.61
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both commands in both examples are *executed*. Only the output of the command after the pipe symbol is actually shown.

In your pipeline, the contents of the `/var/log/messages` file is piped into the input of the `date` command by running `cat` on the left hand side of the pipeline.

The `date` command does not care about its standard input stream and will ignore any data arriving there.  It will, however, produce its own output, which it does on its standard output stream.

The net *visible* result is that the output of the `cat` is ignored and discarded, while the output of `date` is show in the terminal (or wherever the output of the pipeline goes).

What actually happens with the output of the `cat` command is that, since `date` won't read it, the `cat` command is temporarily blocked, waiting for its output to be read (after successfully outputting however much the pipe's buffer can hold; it does not know `date` will never read it).  The `date` command does its thing and outputs its string, after which it terminates.

At that point, when `date` terminates and the standard input stream of `date` is closed, the `cat` command receives a `PIPE` signal by the shell.  This signal tells `cat` that whatever data it's trying to write to its standard output is never going to be read, and it too terminates (terminating on `PIPE` is the default action for this signal).  The rest of the file that `cat` was reading from is never read, and the data in the pipe's buffer is discarded when the shell releases the memory associated with it.

The exact same thing happens with `date` replaced by `w`, or any other command that does not read its standard input stream.

You can compare this with a using a command that actually *does* read its standard input stream:

```
cat /var/log/messages | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

or, without the pipe (as the `cat` is actually not needed in any of these examples),

```
tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' </var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how pipes work: The left hand side command's output is send as input into the right hand side command.

If you want to run two commands one after another, use a semicolon:

```
cat /var/log/messages ; date
```

If you want to run the second command only if the first one is successful, use `&&`:

```
cat /var/log/messages && date
```

If you want to run the second command only if the first one fails, use `||`:

```
cat /var/log/messages || date
```

If you want to run the first command in the background and run the second one at the same time, use `&`

```
cat /var/log/messages & date
```